# MySQL insert multiple rows with select and one constant value

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-insert

i would like to insert two values into a table, one value is constant (user_id) and second values are selected from other table.
I have an error:

> #1064 - Something is wrong in your syntax obok 'select name from payment_methods_default)' w linii 1

```
insert into payment_methods_assigned_to_users (user_id, name)
VALUES (1, select name from payment_methods_default);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`VALUES()` lets you insert just one row, while you want to insert multiple rows (one per row in the `payment_methods_default` table). For this, consider the `insert ... select` syntax:

```
insert into payment_methods_assigned_to_users (user_id, name) 
select 1, name from payment_methods_default
```

Comment: What about multiple rows this way but the FROM table is a subquery?